# Scale object to fit inside certain bounding box three.js

Tags: three.js

In my project i am loading different kinds of model dynamically. How to scale the loaded object so that it fits completely inside a certain bounding box?

To clarify the situation, i do not want the loaded object to fit in my FOV. I already have a house loaded in my scene. I want the new loaded object to fit inside my house.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you do have the bounding box of the house (call it boxH) and the bounding box of the object (call it boxO), take the ratios of the bounding box sizes

```
var sizeH = boxH.getSize(); // get the size of the bounding box of the house
var sizeO = boxO.getSize(); // get the size of the bounding box of the obj

var ratio = sizeH.divide( sizeO ); // get the ratio of the sizes
```

Now `scale()` your object by the inverse maximum value in the `ratio` variable.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to scale according to the value in the `ratio` variable? Suppose the max value in the `ratio` variable is `maxVal`. What should i do then? Should i take `1/maxVal` and set it as the scale value of the object or should i multiply it with the current scale value of the object?

Comment: You should multiply the current scale of the object by `1/maxVal`

Comment: Is maxVal the maximum value between the x, y, z of the resulted Vector3? I tried the solution above and the model became even smaller than before, and inverting the parameters at .divide (size0.divide(sizeH)) made the model bigger but still not big enough.

I did .scale.multiplyScalar(1 / Math.max(ratio.x, ratio.y, ratio.z));