# Position object to fit inside the bounding box of another object three.js

Tags: three.js

In my project i am loading different kinds of model dynamically. I want to keep the loaded model completely inside a preloaded object. I was able to scale the model properly with help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868151/scale-object-to-fit-inside-certain-bounding-box-three-js).

When model geometry is not centered or distance to farthest `X` point from the center of the model is not equal to the farthest `-X` point then the model does not completely fit inside the preloaded model.What happens is, there is some free space on one side while the other side is outside the preloaded model.

Now, how to position the loaded object properly so that it fits completely inside the preloaded model?

Comment: you are pointing out to this exact question in your comment

Comment: this is the correct previous question reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868151

Comment: what do you mean completely. the only other way is for the two objects to exactly match in dimensions (i.e. distorting the size of the second object). Is that what you want?